# Ruby on Rails 3 - Hosting Patterns?

Tags: web-hosting

I'm just starting to give RoR a go (RoR3 to be precise), and I'm wondering about hosting. For PHP applications, it's easy to run multiple of them on the one site (eg. in different subdirectories, subdomains, or addon domains).

It seems that for RoR hosting, it is only ever one application per "server" - so for instance you can no longer install apps in subdirectories.

Is this assumption correct? What are the different ways rails apps are hosted?

Thanks guys :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this assumption is not correctly. There are several solutions to have a Rails application up and running. The right one really depends on the complexity of your project.

If you just need to learn how to use Ruby and you don't want to fight with all the sysadm tasks, then you can give [Heroku](http://heroku.com) a try.

If you want to go with your server, I strongly encourage you to check out [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). It's a Nginx/Apache module you can install to run a Rack (thus a Rails 3) application. And it supports multiple apps on the same server.

For a more technical overview, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728978/recommendations-and-differences-between-different-ruby-on-rails-production-web/1729055#1729055).